# Model binding using Vue.js in Safari

Tags: javascript, model, safari, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an application that is running fine in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari. The problem is a model binding on the below set of radio buttons.

If I console log on the `v-on:change="getQuestions()` call it returns empty but in other browsers it is fine. Could I need a Polyfill?

```
  <div v-for="app in appliances">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="select_appliance">
        <div id="ck-button">
           <label>
             <input type="radio" id="select_button" v-model="appliance"  v-bind:value="app.id" v-on:change="getQuestions()">
             <span><img v-bind:src="app.icon" height="80px" width="auto"></br></br>{{app.appliance}}</span>
           </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**getQuestions**

```
     getQuestions: function (){
       console.log('hi');
       console.log(this.appliance);
       console.log('bye');
       var self = this;
      console.log(self.appliance);
       axios.get('/get_questions/' + this.appliance, {

        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            self.questions = response.data;
            self.numberQuestions = self.questions.questions.length;
            self.getAnswers();


        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
     },
```

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle, or more code ? We don't know how getQuestion method looks like, also you don't need brackets in template when you want to trigger method `v-on:change="getQuestions"` - it totally fine.

Comment: I have added getQuestions @BelminBedak. As you can see me testing the console logs, those are returning empty purely in Safari

Comment: Well I think problem is somewhere else, unit test could detect it.I just tested simplified version and it works pretty fine in latest Safari http://jsbin.com/lelamorale/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Could it be the v-bind to the value causing the problem @BelminBedak

Comment: I don't think so - the pure value shouldn't be issue.